# ENOTFound error installing Gulp-Sass with Bower

Tags: node.js, npm, bower, gulp-sass

I'm new to Node.js, NPM, Bower, gulp et al. I'm trying to integrate with VS2015 running on Windows 10.

So I have installed Node, used NPM to install Bower, Gulp and Gulp-Sass, 
but when I try to use bower to add gulp-sass to the project I get this error:

```
G:\project>bower install gulp-sass --save
bower                        ENOTFOUND Package gulp-sass not found
```

I have tried reinstalling gulp, gulp-sass, node-sass. I've even uninstalled and reinstalled node. But I keep getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, bower is used to manage client-side dependencies.  If you installed gulp-sass with NPM, then that is probably sufficient.  Bower does not contain a package for gulp-sass because it is not typically used client-side.

Comment: Ah, I was following a guide to using it to compile sass in vs2015. I'll test it out later.